# Docker Host Interfaces not cleaning up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Forgive me if any of the following falls in to the 'stupid question' category - still getting spun up on how docker works - only been at it on/off for a month.

I've got a handful of windows docker hosts. When docker spins up our containers it creates a nat network for the containers to communicate on. This consists of creating a Hyper-v virtual adapter as the network gateway, and opening ports 53 for dns and 139 for whatever it does with SMB...

When those containers are stopped, deleted, and the networks pruned it only kills the docker networks - it never goes back and destroys the network adapters that it creates, and they continue to listen on 53 and 139.

Normally this wouldn't be much of an issue, but it seems that when the host has been up long enough, and a bunch of these have built up, we start getting new containers that are unreachable and see errors like this in the logs:

`Resolver Setup/Start failed for container <CONTAINER NAME>, "error in opening name server socket listen udp 172.22.32.1:53: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."`

My assumption here is that it's attempting to create a new network, but one already exists at that address, so it's bombing...

Restarting the docker service clears out all of these stale networks, but it doesn't seem to clean it on its own.

Has anyone else encountered issues like this? Is this desired behavior? Is there some sort of config change I can make to force it to clean up? Am I entirely off base with any of my assumptions?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the port is not already taken by some other process. Can't speak of windows but I don't have any issues on RHEL doing similar work.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. It's pretty difficult to diagnose because the ports in use by docker containers do not show up in netstat on windows, but we don't see anything else running on those ports.

Comment: `docker run -d --name $name --restart=unless-stopped  -p $hostPort:4200 $name` is how I bind mine. Hoping you are doing the same. On windows you can `netstat -a -n -o` to get the process id and then Task manager (Details tab) on windows to associate PID.

Comment: Also try `docker ps` to see if anything running with that port

Comment: Definitely no other docker containers running on the ports in question.

You can actually just toss in the -b flag to netstat and it will tell you the service that's holding it open. No need to correlate in task manager. The only ports that netstat reports though are the docker interface addresses themselves; not the container ports. Those are not exposed to netstat at all - which makes it really hard/annoying to troubleshoot.

Comment: We're starting things like this... 

`docker run -dt -m 6GB --volume $path1 --volume $path2 --volume $path3 --volume $path4 --volume $path5 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -e envVar1=$envVar1 -e envVar2=$envVar2 "${ImageName}"`

Comment: Oh I see you are using/binding ports 80/443. Looking at the error message I see the port in conflict is 53 used for DNS listeners. Not sure why running your image leads to that issue.

Comment: The port conflict is seemingly on the network gateway, which is attempting to start the docker DNS server and is unable to... again, because I suspect that specific network address was already in use because docker never cleans those up.

It's getting that to clean up that I'd like to solve... since restarting the docker daemon all the time just to accomplish that task seems... dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue when docker for desktop crashed. (ran out of memory probably) Even after stopping it, the process 'com.docker.backend.exe' was still running that kept the ports open. Ending the process solved it for me.